# AJAX Sends back entire page instead of result

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am having a little trouble figuring out why my ajax response is sending me the entire page. 
I am not using conventional AJAX code simply because this is how the guy was doing it in a tutorial I was following. I am using firebug to track all my javascript variables and when I break the code at the responseText var it gives me the entire page. Here is the code for the javascript on the page I am working with :

```
function changepass() {
  var u = _("username").value;

  var cp = _("currentPass").value;

  var np = _("newPass").value;

  var cnp = _("confirmNewPass").value;

  if(np != cnp) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "The passwords given do not match!";
  } else if (cp === "" || np === "" || cnp === "") {
    _("status").innerHTML = "Please fill out all of the fields.";
  } else {
    _("changepassbtn").style.display = "none";
    _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
 var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "change_password.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
var response = ajax.responseText;
if(response == "success"){
_("status").innerHTML = "Your password change was successful! Click the button below to proceed.<br><br><a href=\"user.php\" style=\"font-size:\'1.5em\'\">Back To Home Page</a>";
} else if (response == "no_exist"){
_("status").innerHTML = "Your current password was entered incorrectly.";
    _("changepassbtn").style.display = "initial";
} else if(response == "pass_failed"){
_("status").innerHTML = "Change password function failed to execute!";
    _("changepassbtn").style.display = "initial";
} else {
_("status").innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred";
    _("changepassbtn").style.display = "initial";

}
       }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&cp="+cp+"&np="+np+"&cnp"+cnp);
}
}
```

Here is the AJAX code that I use to handle the requests.

```
  function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open( meth, url, true );
        x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return x;
    }

    function ajaxReturn(x){
        if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
           return true; 
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here is the server side PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["u"]) && isset($_POST['oe']) && isset($_POST['ne']) &&    isset($_POST['p'])) {
        $oe = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['oe']);
        $ne = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['ne']);
        $p = md5($_POST['p']);      
        $u = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['u']);
        var_dump($oe, $ne, $p, $u);
        $sql = "SELECT username, password, email FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT   1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);        
        $db_username = $row[0];
        $db_password = $row[1];
        $db_email = $row[2];
        var_dump($db_username, $db_password, $db_email);
        if($db_email != $oe) {
            echo "bad_email";
            exit();
        } else if($db_password != $p) {
            echo "no_exist";
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET email='$ne' WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            $sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
            $db_newemail = $row[0];
            if($db_newemail == $ne) {
                echo "success";
                exit();
            } else {
                echo "email_failed";
                exit();
    }
    }
}
```

My mistake was a simple syntax error.  Gosh PHP is picky! The error occurs in the ajax.send command. I am miss an '=' on the last parameter.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Uhm, seeing the PHP that actually creates the response would be really helpful ?

Comment: I dont know if I would do password testing on client side....

Comment: You mean `response` has an unexpected value? Then you'd need to post the serverside code and some example data for `"u="+u+"&cp="+cp+"&np="+np+"&cnp"+cnp`

Comment: The serverside code is posted. When I debug the JS I find that the var response is equal to the whole page. For example, when I create a break point at the line below the Response declaration it outputs the html for the entire web page.

Comment: This is literally my first website using a user system. I am not versed at all in the security measures I need to take. So, any recommendations would be appreciated. But moot criticism does not help me. I am getting the basic functionality down first, then I will go back and make the necessary changes. That may not be the best way to do it, but I am pressed for time to get this project done.

Comment: `$_POST['oe']` (and others) are NOT set, so it's skipping that if block.  Unless there are mistakes in your javascript code.